# Why can't I use a variable immediately after it is initialised in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Why can't I use a variable immediately after it is initialised in a class?

```
1. class A:
2.     var1 = <call_to_a_function_outside_class_A>
3.     Var2 = <something_to_with_var1>
....
```

I get

```
NameError: name 'var1' is not defined (at line number 3)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the actual code you are using?

Comment: @Axe319 I wish, I could. But, it's kind of confidential. I'm really sorry. I hope you understand. The code is similar to the pseudo code.

Comment: @Rabindra You need to have a [mre]. You don't have to have the exact code, just actual code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman This question does not need minimal reproducible example. Because, this is a very general code. As answered by Soroush, below, you can create any class and instance variables and the error will be reproducible. I'm not being rude or anything. I don't know why the question was marked closed.

Comment: You should always provide one. It'll help people to easier understand the question, both for people who try to answer and people with the same question. The answer below is, by your question wrong, as `var1` is *not* a `call_to_a_function_outside_class_A`. Also, `var2`, being `something_to_with_var1`, will *not* cause any problems *unless* in the very specific case where `var2` is a closure that is binding `var1` but incorrectly referencing it. It would work if it was an expression, function/lambda with in-parameter or a correctly bound.

Comment: So no, you can't create any class or any class variable. There are in fact more cases that don't reproduce that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have something like this: (A lambda/function which has `var1` inside)

```py
class A:
    var1 = 10
    var2 = lambda: print(var1)
    
A.var2()  # NameError: name 'var1' is not defined
```

The reason is because of Python's scoping rules. The methods inside the class are not *nested* in class, which means if Python couldn't find a variable inside the methods, it will not check the class's namespace to find that.
**Instead** it will look at the class's enclosing scope which is the module's namespace(`globals()` dictionary) here, to see if there is a `var1` there:

```py
class A:
    var1 = 10
    var2 = lambda: print(var1)

var1 = "something"
A.var2()  # "something"
```

If you need to access class variable inside the methods, you could either hard-code the class's name (`print(A.var1)`) or use `__class__`: (I will use `def` keyword and regular methods here, also calling the method from instance)

```py
class A:
    var1 = 10
    def my_method(self):
        print(self.__class__.var1)
        print(A.var1)

var1 = "something"
obj = A()
obj.my_method()
```

output:

```
10
10
```